# Unable to get most important tourist places like Google Thing to do does

Tags: api, maps

I'm trying to find out which are the main tourist attractions in a city or country, I found this Google website called Things to Do ([link](https://www.google.com/travel/things-to-do?dest_src=ut&tcfs=EhEKCC9tLzA1cXRqEgVQYXJpcw&dest_mid=%2Fm%2F05qtj&dest_state_type=main&ved=0CAUQyJABahcKEwiQ54O66KX1AhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQeQ&ictx=3#ttdm=48.823203_2.236300_11&ttdmf=%252Fm%252F04gdr)) that does exactly what I want. I trying to get this data with Google Maps API, but I haven't being able to find these results anyhow.

I'm using Paris as an example because clearly first place most be Eiffel Tower and the web I mentioned says so. I'm using calling https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=paris+point+of+interest&rankby=prominence but I don't even get Eiffel Tower in the 60 results the API returns.

Someone have some experience trying to do something similar or knows what maybe my problem?

Comment: https://github.com/tuhinpal/thingstodo

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with something similar and I don't think it's particularly easy to get sensible results with the Places API.

As far as I can tell the `rankBy` option you're using only applies to the `nearbysearch` endpoint. See the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#rankby). However that type of search is based on specific coordinates with the radius limited to 50km. That's fine for local or specific city searches but not so much for wider regions and countries.

The `point+of+interest` `textsearch` query you're using isn't too bad but the quality of the results is mixed and seem to get worse the wider the search area you use. For example, if you use `query=australia+point+of+interest` the top result looks to be the Principality Stadium in Cardiff, UK.

So far the best search criteria I've found covering city and country regions is with `things+to+do` as part of the query instead, e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=things+to+do+paris

The top results for that include *Arc de Triomphe, Sacre Coeur, Champ de Mars, Louvre Museum and Eiffel Tower* which is a bit more like what you'd expect. The `textsearch` endpoint doesn't have any sorting available but if you look at enough results you might be able to sort yourself based on something like the `rating` and `user_ratings_total` fields in the response.